# Laravel can't set class variable in constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a private variable in my class that I want to be set to the authenticated user. For some reason, though, I can't get the variable to be set inside of the constructor. Here is what I have so far:

```
private $user = null;


  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

 public function index()
    {
        $return['Admin'] = $this->user;

        return view('home', compact('return'));
    }
```

The variable `$user` stays null for some reason though. When I use `Auth::user()` in place of $this->user though, it works just fine. I have set variables from the constructor multiple times in the past and this is the first time it hasn't worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.3 you are no longer able to access session in controller constructors, [because middleware has not run yet](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-session-in-constructor).

[You can define a closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) (scroll to "Session In The Constructor") that happens after the session middleware has ran.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm.